# [HASKELL]Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `[a1] -> Bool'

Tags: haskell, match

I`m trying to write  a function for reading line by line from a file:

```
readMyFile = do 
          contents <- readFile "input.txt"
          if(null sStringV == True)
                then do
                    let sStringV = lines contents
                    let sString = head sStringV
                    let sStringV = tail sStringV
                    return sString
                else do
                    let sString = head sStringV
                    let sStringV = tail sStringV
                    return sString
```

and I declared sStringV as null

```
sStringV    = null
```

When I compile this code I'm getting the following error.

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `[a1] -> Bool'
In the first argument of `null', namely `sStringV'
In the first argument of `(==)', namely `null sStringV'
In the expression: (null sStringV == True)
```

I don't understand where my problem is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` is a function `[a] -> Bool` and returns whether the input list is empty. Therefore `sStringV` has type `[a] -> Bool`.

In the line `if (null sStringV == True)`

the argument to `null` should be a list, not the `null` function itself.

It seems you should change the declaration of `sStringV` to something like

```
sStringV :: String
sStringV = ""
```

However, you should be aware that `let sStringV = lines contents` does not assign a new value to `sStringV` - it only declares a new variable `sStringV` which hides the old definition. You can't modify `sStringV` from within your `readMyFile` function.

It looks like you're trying to use Haskell like an imperative language.

Answer (score 0):

null() does not test whether a variable is null.  null() tests whether a list is empty.   The key word is **list**, i.e. you have to call null on a list.  So you have two choices:

1) You can call null() on an empty list:

```
null []  -->True
```

2) You can call null() on a list that contains something:

```
null [1, 2, 3]  --> False
```

Also note that writing:

```
if(null sStringV == True)
```

is redundant.  null() takes a list as an argument and returns True if the list is empty, and False if the list contains something.  Therefore, all you need to write is:

```
if(null sStringV)
then do ....   --executed if sStringV is an empty list

else do ...    --excuted if sStringV is a list that contains something
```

Here is an example:

```
dostuff:: [a] -> IO () 
dostuff alist = if null alist
                then putStrLn "hello"
                else putStrLn "goodbye"

ghci>:l 1.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 1.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
ghci>dostuff []
hello
ghci>dostuff [1, 2, 3]
goodbye
ghci>
```

Comment: @Elena Dobosariu, some more advice.